# how to change the position of image inside cell of uitableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have added an image to the cell of a uitableview, but when I tried to change the position of the image nothing happened.

This is what my tableview function looks like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let article = articles[indexPath.row] as Article

    cell.textLabel!.text = article.title

    cell.imageView?.image = article.image
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    cell.imageView?.frame = rect

    return cell
}
```

As you can see the image shows up but the position stays the same:

[image: ur.com/1EP0o.png]

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: You need to subclass UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`
- Ensure that your cell will be used in the tableView
- Override `layoutSubviews`

  ```
  class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()

      self.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: i am trying to change position of expanded cell....but it only works after second expand....any suggestion?